# How to search website content and store it in Excel?

Tags: linux, excel, grep

We have a website that shows contents example like:

```
Lines of code
12333 
Issues 
235
Coverage
67.5%
etc.
```

in which the data automatically updates in certain time.
Using Linux I have to write shell script to fetch the data above and push that data into Excel sheet. I have used `grep` but unable to do.

Comment: fetch web content, pls check `curl`, extract the data you want, check `grep` for excel, Linux shell usually doesn't talk to Microsoft directly. You can put data in csv format,  It can be imported in Excel.  . For transforming data into csv, you could take a look `awk`.  Now you may want to show your codes?

Comment: Thanx kent, I followed the same approach now i have all my data in text file and i am writing that data into excel using awd the code i used is 
 awk '{print $1}' OFS="|" input.txt > OutputObatained.xls  
The issue i am facing is i want my data to be stored in row wise but the is stored column wise. Please help ..

Answer (score 0):

This line will help:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",NR==1?"":"|",$0}END{print ""}' file(or your input)
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  cat f
Lines of code
12333 
Issues 
235
Coverage
67.5%
etc.

kent$  awk '{printf "%s%s",NR==1?"":"|",$0}END{print ""}' f
Lines of code|12333 |Issues |235|Coverage|67.5%|etc.
```